# File synchronization tool

Tags: software-recommendation

I am running Ubuntu 13.04, Gnome Shell 3.6.3.1.

I need to synchronize a local folder with a remote folder. The folder contains files (binary and text). There are no symlinks or hard links. But there are folders within folders. The remote system allows webdavs and ftp access. I will prefer to use webdavs, I think it is more secure than ftp.

What is the best tool for the job? I will prefer a GUI tool but a command-line option that is easy to configure will also do.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't use this tool. But I think this suites your requirement. 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/webdav-sync/

Comment: Does grsync support webdavs? I tried entering my davs/ webdavs address in source or destination. It did not work :(

Comment: sorry grsync will not support webdav but try this new tool.